# What's the difference between non-unique key lookup and index range scan?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I don't know what's the difference between non-unique key lookup and index range scan because I think both of them return rows which follow a condition like the operator "=" o "<".

Comment: They correspond to different search operations. What is the background of your question?

Answer (score 5):

```
WHERE x = 123   -- with INDEX(x)
```

will scan all the row or rows with x=123.  It performs identically to

```
WHERE y BETWEEN 22 and 33   -- with any kind of index on y
```

Both will drill down the BTree of the index to find the first match.  Then it will scan forward until the value no longer matches.

However, these work differently:

```
WHERE x = 123              AND b >= 88
WHERE y BETWEEN 22 and 33  AND b >= 88
```

The first can take advantage of `INDEX(x,b)`.  It locates the first `x=123 and b=88`, then scans until `x > 123`.

The second cannot do anything like that.  No composite index will really handle both `y` and `b`.

"Index range scan" and "table range scan" are similar, but applied to different BTrees.  The "table" is contained in a BTree that is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY` so, arguably, a "table range scan" is an "index range scan"

A "unique key lookup" and a "non-unique key lookup" differ in that the unique one can stop after finding 1 row (or no rows), where as the non-unique one must keep going until a non-matching value is encountered (or `LIMIT` is reached).

Answer (score 0):

I think for the most part it is semantics.  The two are very similar.

An index range scan starts with a lookup.  In some cases, that is sufficient.  For instance;

- To find a maximum or minimum value.
- If the index is known to be `unique` and the comparison is equality (or `is  null`).

More generally, the engine continues scanning the index either until the key value changes (for an `=` comparison) or until the end of the range.